# What is the alternative of selenium.isElementPresent in Webdriver

Tags: xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Hi I need to check a drop down field is having given values but those values are not selected so its not getting displayed in the dropdown box.
I have following Xpath for the element

```
//table[contains(@id,'Field')]//tr[td//span[text()='Code']]/preceding-sibling::*[1]/td//select[contains(@id,'GSRCH_FLT')]/option[text()='not=']
```

which is identifying the element properly in the browser.  But when I am using the following webdriver method to verify it

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[contains(@id,'Field')]//tr[td//span[text()='Code']]/preceding-sibling::*[1]/td//select[contains(@id,'GSRCH_FLT')]/option[text()='not=']")).isDisplayed();
```

its returning false since it is not getting displayed in the box.

Can u tell me the alternative for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want:

```
private boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver, By by){
    return driver.findElements(by).count != 0;
}
```

`findElements()` is better for this than `findElement()` because it won't wait if the element isn't present.  If you're running with implicit waits turned on, `findElement()` will time out looking for the element (that's the exception you're catching), and it will take a while.

Comment: Why is the return testing equality with zero if you are testing if an element is present?

Comment: @MatthewLock DOH!  Thanks, the comparison was inverted, it's now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I found out that WebDriver does not have a function called `isElementPresent()`. This was one of the important functions that was used in Selenium-1.0.
To implement this in WebDriver you just need to write a method as mentioned below. You can then  use this function with any type of `By` (By.id, BY.name, etc.)

```
private boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver, By by){
  try{
    driver.findElement(by);
    return true;
  }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
    return false;
  }
}
```

And here is an example of how you would call this function

```
if (isElementPresent(by.id("btnSubmit")) {
   // preform some actions
}
```

The above function will return true in case the element is found on the page, else it will return false.

Comment: @Arun the code above is easier to read and is reusable. The only further suggestion is to improve the code include the timeout. Since usually the check is for element to appear is some time-frame.

Comment: -1 for `findElement()`-with-timeout instead of `findElements()`-with-count.

Answer (score 0):

```
    internal static bool IsElementPresent(IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutSeconds=10)
    {

        for (int second = 0; second< timeoutSeconds ; second++)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.FindElement(by);
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                continue;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **isDisplayed()** for verifying whether an element is available on the page.